# Did any Jesuit opponents of early Jansenism argue that Augustine was wrong on any points?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, reformation, augustine, jansenism

Cornelius Jansen is known as the intellectual father of [Jansenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansenism), a movement [not unlike Calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52916/21576) in a few respects, like its emphasis on original sin and predestination.  Jansen's book, *Augustinus* (published 1640), focuses on the works of Augustine to argue for these doctrines.

Opponents to Jansenism didn't waste any time; Wikipedia indicates that Jesuits "designated" Nicolas Caussin and François Pinthereau to write anti-Jansenist works in the 1640s.  By the following decade, the movement had been condemned by the Pope.

Of course, Augustine was and is a highly regarded Christian theologian, though the Catholic church today recognizes that he was sometimes mistaken.  But I'd like to know if the anti-Jansenists were willing to make that admission, or if they focused their attack solely on Jansen's arguments.  So my question is:

**Did the anti-Jansenist writings published before the papal condemnation ever directly say that Augustine was wrong on a particular point, or did they exclusively argue that Jansen and his followers had misused or misinterpreted Augustine?**

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, the detractors of Jansen argued that the doctrine of the *Augustinus* [*or, what they said it was*] wasn’t the one of St Augustine. Two examples of it in:

- *[Les Véritables sentimens de saint Augustin et de l'Église, touchant la grâce](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k96175525/)* by Claude Morel (1650)
  `[Translation: The true sentiments of St Augustine and of the Church about the grace]`
- *[Les sentimens de saint Augustin sur la grace opposez a ceux de Jansenius](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BzLs51Cc9NkC)*, by the oratorian Jean Le Porcq (1700)
  `[Translation: The sentiments of St Augustine about the grace, opposed to the one of Jansen]`

The titles of those books are quite clear, and if you are unsure, just consider the summary of the first one, e.g.:

> Chap. III: Éclaircissment de quelques passages de S. Augustin dont abusent ceux qui veulent lui faire dire contre sa pensée que Jésus-Christ n’est pas mort pour tous les hommes.

Finally an other quotation from the *[Refutation des critiques de Monsieur Bayle sur Saint Augustin](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1QygAAAAMAAJ)* (1782), by the jesuit [Charles Merlin](http://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb10632476n):

> L’*Augustin* de Jansenius n’est qu’un centon composé de plusieurs textes de Saint Augustin pris à contre-sens.
>
> **Translation**: The *Augustine* of Jansenius isn’t anything else than a mingle-mangle of Saint Augustine’s texts in the wrong sense.

Comment: I think Nathaniel is aware that Jesuits argued that Jansenists had misused and misinterpreted Augustine, which your answer demonstrates. However, I don't see how your answer goes anywhere beyond that; the question asked, "Did they ***exclusively*** argue that Jansen and his followers had misused or misinterpreted Augustine?" It's a hard question to answer, and I'm not sure if you have.

Comment: **Exclusively** is a bit hard to answer. However, e.g. on moral questions they sometimes assumed to have different positions than Augustine (Lessius) ; but that wasn't in texts written **against** jansenists as they attacked the *Augustinus* on theological questions (the grace efficacious by itself).